# TestHazelcastFactory client mock is not working

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I am trying to use TestHazelcastFactory to make the Mocked hazelcast client to connect to Mocked HazelCast intance.Here is the code i have tried

**Server**

```
TestHazelcastFactory factory = new TestHazelcastFactory();
 HazelcastInstance instance= factory.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

**Client**

```
TestHazelcastFactory factory = new TestHazelcastFactory();
HazelcastInstance instance= factory.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

But it not able to connect to the mocked Hazelcast Instance.

Comment: Please share member's and client's config

Comment: the config is nothing but just username and password.Its doesnot have any other details

Comment: Dear @pppavan, kindly review my answer and accept it if you have no further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to have `hazelcast-tests.jars` and `hazelcast-client-tests.jar`

`testCompile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:$HZ_VERSION:tests"
testCompile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:$HZ_VERSION:tests"`

Next, you need to use same `TestHazelcastFactory` to clear `HazelcastInstance` for the members and the clients.

Check this snippet

```
    TestHazelcastFactory testHazelcastFactory = new TestHazelcastFactory();

    HazelcastInstance member = testHazelcastFactory.newHazelcastInstance();
    IMap<Object, Object> testMap1 = member.getMap("test");
    testMap1.put(1, "test");

    HazelcastInstance client = testHazelcastFactory.newHazelcastClient();
    IMap<Object, Object> testMap2 = client.getMap("test");
    Object o = testMap2.get(1);
    System.out.println("o = " + o);
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Cheers,

Vik